# how to make a angular modal resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a modal in angular that displays data.

I would like to resize it. I used jQueryUI for that.But resizable works only horizontally when done vertically only the jQueryUI handle moves and the modal remains stationary.

I display my modal using a template as follows.

```
$timeout(function () {                     
    var resizeOptions = { handles: 'all'};
    $(".modal-dialog").draggable();
    $(".modal-dialog").resizable(resizeOptions);
}, 0);                                                                                                                         

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tablemodal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title">Chart Data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table-responsive" data-pattern="priority-columns" data-focus-btn-icon="fa-asterisk" data-sticky-table-header="true" data-add-display-all-btn="true" data-add-focus-btn="true">
            <table cellspacing="0" class="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>x</th>                       
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="close();">Close</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I noticed that mark up in the template is broken you have opend a row but not closed it  with <tr><th>x</th> .  You might want to look at putting <tr><td>x</td></tr> so that your template parses correctly - JQueryUI may not wrap all you contents propery and get it wrong

Comment: yeah that was a mistake but adding it dint make any changes to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to avoid making own modals when we have awesome libraries available out there like [ngModal](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) and many more. Here i am explaining how to use ngModal.

you have to run following command to install this

```
bower install ngModal
```

or if you want to add this into your bower.json file as follows

```
dependencies: {
 "ngModal": "~1.2.0"
}
```

and run following commands after adding into bower.json

```
npm install
bower install
```

To use the library, add the JS file and CSS file, and then include the module in your app:

```
app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngModal"])
```

and you are good to go like this

```
<modal-dialog show='dialogShown' dialog-title='My Dialog' height='400px' width='75%'>
  <p>Dialog content goes in here</p>
</modal-dialog>
```

Comment: how can I resize this dynamically by using something similar to a jquery ui handle.

Comment: my problem is similar to the following plunker, plnkr.co/edit/yzxtWwZQdq94Tagdiswa?p=preview .It could be resized horizontally and vertically only the handle moves.